# Multiple types of onmouseover="bigImg(this)" one one sheet

Tags: onmouseover

I'm such a novice and I'm sure there is a simple solution so I humbly ask for your assistance.

I have a page that has two different types of image buttons; square and rectangle.  The 'onmouseover="bigImg(this)"' works great with the square images but when it comes to the rectangular image button, it scrunches it up to try and make a square.

I know that the image size is defined like this:

```
function bigImg(x) {
    x.style.height = "64px";
    x.style.width = "64px";
}

function normalImg(x) {
    x.style.height = "32px";
    x.style.width = "32px";
}
```

My problem is that it applies to the rectangular image buttons too.

Question:  Is there a way to make those "functions" into a class or id where I could specify it on the code...
OR is there a better solution?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly. If you don’t want this function to be called for your rectangular images - then why do you put `onmouseover="bigImg(this)"` on those in the first place?

Comment: I found a sloppy solution where I resize my long button on Photoshop to work with the same heights as the other icons.  I set the width = "auto".

If any anyone has a more elegant solution, please, please, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a newbie, I find a lot of answers here.  Thank you all for your posts.

On this one, I just showed you all how much of a newbie I am...

BigImg is just a name, not a function.  I just changed BigImg to BigButton and I was able to isolate the buttons from everything else.

Hope this helps anyone else that was in my shoe.

Answer (score 0):

I found a sloppy solution where I resize my long button on Photoshop to work with the same heights as the other icons. I set the width = "auto".

If any anyone has a more elegant solution, please, please, please let me know.

Thank you.